# Angular2 Modal/Popup box wont appear when clicked

Tags: jquery, angular, mean-stack

I'm trying to make a popup appear over a google map in Angular2/5, the modal stays hidden when the button is clicked. I'm using the MEAN stack and have tried debugging with console.logs which show me that it makes it to my component ts file then the service but the LESS is never activated to show the modal and no log is triggered in the modal.component.ts. this is the tutorial ive been following is the something im missing to get this to work with the MEAN stack and nodejs? http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2017/01/24/angular-2-custom-modal-window-dialog-box

Modal.compomemt.ts:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { ModalService } from '../_services/index';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id.toString(),
    selector: 'modal',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})

export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
@Input() id: string;
private element: JQuery;

constructor(private modalService: ModalService, private el: ElementRef) {
    this.element = $(el.nativeElement);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    let modal = this;

    // ensure id attribute exists
    if (!this.id) {
        console.error('modal must have an id');
        return;
    }

    // move element to bottom of page (just before </body>) so it can be displayed above everything else
    this.element.appendTo('body');

    // close modal on background click
    this.element.on('click', function (e: any) {
        var target = $(e.target);
        if (!target.closest('.modal-body').length) {
            modal.close();
        }
    });

    // add self (this modal instance) to the modal service so it's accessible from controllers
    this.modalService.add(this);
}

// remove self from modal service when directive is destroyed
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.modalService.remove(this.id);
    this.element.remove();
}

// open modal
open(): void {
    this.element.show();
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
}

// close modal
close(): void {
    this.element.hide();
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
}
}
```

modal.service.ts:

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';

export class ModalService {
private modals: any[] = [];

add(modal: any) {
    // add modal to array of active modals
    this.modals.push(modal);
}

remove(id: string) {
    // remove modal from array of active modals
    let modalToRemove = _.findWhere(this.modals, { id: id });
    this.modals = _.without(this.modals, modalToRemove);
}

open(id: string) {
    // open modal specified by id
    console.log(id + " Service!!!");
    let modal = _.findWhere(this.modals, { id: id });
    console.log(modal);
    modal.open();
}

close(id: string) {
    // close modal specified by id
    let modal = _.find(this.modals, { id: id });
    modal.close();
}
```

}

the code in my main component the calls open and close to the service:

```
openModal(id: string){
    console.log(id);
    this.modalService.open(id);
}

closeModal(id: string){
    this.modalService.close(id);
}
```

Modal.less:

```
modal {
/* modals are hidden by default */
display: none;

.modal {
    /* modal container fixed across whole screen */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    /* z-index must be higher than .modal-background */
    z-index: 1000;

    /* enables scrolling for tall modals */
    overflow: auto;

    .modal-body {
        padding: 20px;
        background: #fff;

        /* margin exposes part of the modal background */
        margin: 40px;
    }
}

.modal-background {
    /* modal background fixed across whole screen */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    /* semi-transparent black  */
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.75;

    /* z-index must be below .modal and above everything else  */
    z-index: 900;
}
}

body.modal-open {
    /* body overflow is hidden to hide main scrollbar when modal window is open */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing yourself a disservice if you learn angular by following the example at that link. There are Angular ways to do this. I'd recommend you to look at things like Material2 and CDK and find tutorials about them instead, ditch jquery and start from scratch. Sorry, bad answer but I just can't stand by idle as people teach people to do it the wrong way. Ready to risk a downvote for this principle :)

Comment: Ive ditched these popups anyway as nothing i tried will work just gunna use normal componenets